# Garbage values are contained at the end of the array after using strtok

Tags: arrays, c, strtok, garbage

While printing out the values in array time I'm getting the values in str and additional garbage values. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[100];
scanf("%[^\n]s", &str);

int i = 0;
char *p = strtok (str, " ");
char *time[100];

while (p != NULL)
{
    time[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}

i=0;
while(time[i]!='\0')
{
       printf("%s\n", time[i]);
       i++;
}


    return 0;

}
```

I'me getting this output in stdout

[image]

Comment: You should definitely be compiling with warnings enabled.

Comment: `<source>:21:14: warning: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Wpointer-compare]
   21 | while(time[i]!='\0')
      |              ^~
<source>:21:7: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
   21 | while(time[i]!='\0')
      |       ^`

Comment: What makes you think there will be a sentinel `NULL` pointer value anyway? Your loop specifically prevents it being placed in the array, and the array was not initialised with any values. I suggest `while ((time[i++] = p) != NULL) { p = strtok (NULL, " "); }`